catch on a Promise
I am new to Javascript and trying to understand how Promise really works. I understand basics of how chaining works in Promise.
Is version 1 equivalent to version 2.
How does version 2 works? Since "catch" is chained to "then", does "then" returns a "Promise"?
version 1:
const pr = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const test = false;

  if (test) {
    resolve("Promise resolved");
  } else {
    reject("Promise Rejected");
  }
});

pr.then((resolve) => console.log(resolve));

pr.catch((error) => console.log(error));


version 2:
const pr = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  const test = false;

  if (test) {
    resolve("Promise resolved");
  } else {
    reject("Promise Rejected");
  }
});

pr.then((resolve) => console.log(resolve))
.catch((error) => console.log(error));


First version they will act independently. Second version they act in sequence. Refer to this article. Version 2 is recommended.

'does "then" returns a "Promise"': that's what the documentation says: "Returns a new Promise immediately."

The first version is a verbose way to write pr.then(successCallback, errorCallback). See duplicate reference.

@zer00ne, I actually read the link you sent before posting this, it still doesn't makes sense how version 2 works. How does the catch get invoked?

@trincot, I am not able to understand how version 2 works as ".then" and ".catch" are chained. So when "pr" gets rejected, it will first call .then with (null, null) , how does it then calls ".catch"? What does .then(null, null) returns?

Hi @jay26 go to the summary and also try out the task.

I'd like to also refer the OP to this excellent (but quite detailed) article which might clarify things: https://dev.to/lydiahallie/javascript-visualized-promises-async-await-5gke

@jay26 click the solution button in task. It explains that the chained "thenables" will return a promise no matter what. In that particular example the first .then() will run then if it fails, then the catch will run and a promise is returned in that order. The other version if the first .then() fails the catch will not happen after it since they don't run in sequence.
